# Do these enemies ever stop spawning?

Tags: ios, hero-of-sparta-2

I am in the first level, just past the second loading screen. The Spartan knocks over a large statue (looks like a globe of water with a serpent wrapped around it) and jumps down into the room behind it. This room has wheels on the walls that you can interact with.

Enemies spawn continuously in this room, in waves of 3-4.  I've probably killed 10 waves.

Will these enemies keep spawning indefinitely until I mess with the wheels? Can I just grind them for orbs as long as I feel like?

Comment: Only one way to find out...

Comment: By fighting them until my phone runs out of batteries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they do spawn over and over again, so you can do whatever you like with them. I just killed them until I got bored of it. And I got a good amount of orbs out of it.